# Any book or PDF for over 300 single-worded prepositions

Tags: support, feature-request

Recently, I came to know that there are 336 prepositions in English via reading an **[OUP blog](https://blog.oup.com/2007/08/prepositions/)**:

> ... . And now the lowly preposition is finally getting the attention it deserves with The Preposition Project (TPP), a monumental undertaking that systematically describes 673 distinct senses for **334 prepositions** in English.

I tried my best to find over 330 prepostions in English, but could find a PDF [book](https://www.pdfdrive.com/english-preposition-list-e32281720.html) (written by Josef Essberger) that just provides 150+ prepositions, from which 40% are phrasal prepositions.

Is there any book which can provide over 300 single-worded prepositions? I am from **Pakistan**, and I hope that those books would be available on major cities like **Karachi** and **Islamabad**. If it's not feasible, what PDF documents are there to fit this need? Can you yourself provide over 300 prepositions?

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would downvote this request, maybe you're asking someone to actually list all 300 prepositions (first time I ever heard that number) is unrealistic. I'm almost tempted to think this question should be migrated on the main page.

Comment: Good ole Wiktionary, despite its many detractors you often find stuff that you can't find anywhere else: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions It lists around 170 prepositions of which you can safely ignore 70 :)

Comment: "*[This total of 150 prepositions](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/prepositions/list.htm) is comprehensive at the time of writing, and represents all the prepositions currently found in a good English dictionary.*" [English Club] Memorising or studying 300+ prepositions, when you find that list, is a waste of time IMO. And by the way, the reference you cite **does *not* say that all 300 prepositions are single words.**

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Entirely satified with your comments... In addition to all of this, there are some prepositions, which are used in particular regions. For instance, **fornent** (=meaning face to face) is a preposition, which is solely used in Scottish and North Irish English. So I am sure its substitute might be the preposition vis-à-vis, which can be used across the world without any restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't tried it myself, it looks like you can download the list of prepositions that your link is talking about [here](http://www.clres.com/db/registration.php?download=tpp) by filling out your name, email, etc. I'm not convinced that the list only contains prepositions because I searched their page [here](http://www.clres.com/cgi-bin/onlineTPP/find_prep.cgi) for `*` and got a lot of phrases such as "by the name of".

If that doesn't work, then you could try:

- Searching [Dante](http://dante.skxmlbox.idm.fr/dante/search/Result.html?queryId=65830914&queryDescription=Advanced%20search%3A%20preposition).
- The Moby Project's [list](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3203/files/mobypos.txt). Following the method I outlined in [a previous answer of mine](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11760/191178), that ends up being these 162 words/phrases:

  ```
  a la,abaft,aboard,aboon,about,above,across,adown,aff,afore,after,against,alongside,along,amidst,amid,amongst,among,anear,anenst,anent,around,aslant,astraddle,astride,as,athwart,atop,atween,at,a,barring,bar,bating,before,behind,below,beneath,ben,besides,beside,between,betwixt,beyond,but,by,chez,circa,concerning,considering,contra,cum,d',despite,des,de,di,down,during,ere,excepting,except,ex,failing,fer,forby,fore,fornenst,fornent,forth,for,frae,from,inby,inside,into,in,lacking,less,like,malgré,maugre,midst,mid,minus,natheless,near-hand,near,neath,next,nigh,notwithstanding,o' ,o'er,o',off,of,onto,on,opposite,opuscule,outshout,outside,outwith,out,over,pace,past,pending,per,plus,pro,qua,reference,regarding,respecting,re,roundabout,round,sans,save,saving,secundum,senza,since,sine,sith,sur,syne,tae,than,thro',throughout,through,thro,thru,thwart,till,touching,towards,toward,to,underneath,under,unless,unlike,until,unto,up-and-down,upon,up,versus,via,vice,visard,wantage,wanting,while,withal,within,without,with
  ```
- The OED's advanced search, assuming you have a subscription or are willing to pay for one.