# How many unique four-letter words are in the English language that fall within the major word classes?

Tags: discussion, resources

To better clarify: I would like to find some way (be it just the raw information itself in a pastebin, a dictionary crawler, a website search function, or something else) to determine how many words there are in English that

1. Are exactly four letters long
2. Fall into the major word classes, i.e. nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs - entirely EXCLUDING prepositions, pronouns, determiners, conjunctions, or interjections
3. Aren't just other words with added plurality, like the three-letter word Aid being made four letters by turning it into Aids; basically, no words that are included in the dictionary purely as a different form, tense, etc. of an existing word

I can scroll through the final list manually, that's not a problem. I just can't find a site or resource that makes it easy to search words not just by letter length but also by word class. Thank you!

Comment: You could download an English corpus with part-of-speech tagging, and work from there.

Comment: You could probably extract it from a [Wiktionary data dump](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Help:FAQ#Downloading_Wiktionary) too. No idea how easily...

Comment: Here is a [list of 4-letter words](https://7esl.com/4-letter-words/) organised by parts of speech. IDK how exhaustive it is. Crossword helpers might be of use to you.

Comment: The 7esl list isn't very comprehensive - the adjectives don't include *lost*, *mute*, or *tame*, for instance. But it's not clear how comprehensive it has to be for the OP's requirements.

Comment: While interesting, this seems more of a 'how do I find this file, or how do I program this?' kind of question, which might be better suited on the main programming site [stackoverflow.se](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: You can try using this: https://www.visca.com/regexdict/

Comment: @Mitch As currently written it's not on topic on Stack Overflow. "I have this PoS tagged file; how do I parse it using [language]?" would be on topic on SO though it really should show attempts to solve it in [language].

Comment: @Laurel I guess it is on topic for meta.elu to have links to elsewhere (even if those links are not the best). The OP presumably just wants this list without any indication of programming. But I've seen similar requests (but with a more explicit programming feel) on SE.

Comment: @StuartF Sorry, to be clear: I'm trying to figure out literally every last word within this specification, so, as comprehensive as possible - BUT, it doesn't really matter all that much if just a few are missing. The thing I need this for is a side project idea that I'm doing for the heck of it, so it's mostly whatever. At worst, even just having like 75 percent of the relevant words would still be very useful.

Comment: @Mitch and Laurel Yeah sorry, I wasn't sure, I'm new here! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [PoS-tagged wordlist from the Moby Project](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/3203/files/mobypos.txt) (as described in [another answer of mine](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11760/191178)) and regex, I made a list.

Regex:

```
^([a-z]{4})\\[\S]*?[VNAv]
```

It's not perfect, since it only matches the 26 lowercase letters of the alphabet (*café* and *wi-fi* wouldn't match, for example).

Results:

```
abac
abba
abbr
abed
abet
able
ably
abox
abri
abut
acad
acce
acct
aced
ache
acid
acle
acme
acne
acpt
acre
actg
acus
acyl
adat
adit
adjt
advt
adze
aeon
aero
aery
aesc
afar
agal
agar
agba
agcy
aged
agee
agha
agio
agit
agly
agma
agog
agon
agst
ague
aide
airt
airy
ajar
ajee
akee
akin
alae
alap
alar
alba
alec
alee
alfa
alga
alif
alit
alky
ally
aloe
alow
also
alto
alum
amah
amal
amba
ambo
amen
amic
amie
amir
ammo
amok
amyl
anal
anat
anba
anes
anew
anga
anil
anim
anis
ankh
anna
anoa
anon
ansa
anta
ante
anti
anus
aoli
aped
apex
appd
apse
aqua
arak
arca
arch
arco
arcs
area
areg
aria
arid
aril
army
arri
arse
arty
arum
arvo
aryl
asci
ashy
assn
asst
astr
atar
atom
atop
atry
atty
auld
aune
aunt
aura
auth
auto
avdp
aver
avid
away
awed
awry
axed
axel
axes
axil
axis
axle
axon
ayah
ayin
ayre
azan
baal
baas
baba
babe
babu
baby
bach
back
bact
bade
bael
baff
bagh
baht
bail
bait
bake
bald
bale
balk
ball
balm
banc
band
bane
bang
bani
bank
bant
barb
bard
bare
bark
barm
barn
barr
base
bash
bass
bast
bate
bath
bats
batt
baud
bawd
bawl
baya
bead
beak
beam
bean
bear
beat
beau
beck
beef
beek
been
beep
beer
beet
beld
bell
belt
bema
bend
bene
bent
berg
berk
berm
best
beta
beth
bevy
bhut
bias
bibb
bibl
bice
bide
bidi
bier
biff
biga
bigg
bike
bile
bilk
bill
bind
bine
bing
bint
biog
biol
bird
biri
birk
birl
birr
bise
bish
bisk
bist
bite
bitt
bize
bkcy
bklr
bkpr
blab
blae
blah
blas
blat
bldg
bleb
blet
blew
blip
blob
bloc
blot
blow
blub
blue
blur
blvd
boar
boas
boat
bobs
bode
body
boff
bogy
boil
boko
bola
bold
bole
boll
bolo
bolt
boma
bomb
bond
bone
bong
bony
boob
bood
book
boom
boon
boor
boot
bora
bord
bore
bori
born
bort
bosh
bosk
boss
bots
bott
boud
bouk
bout
bowl
boyo
bozo
brad
brae
brag
bran
brat
braw
bray
bred
bree
brei
brev
brew
brie
brig
brim
brio
brit
brob
broo
bros
brow
brut
bskt
btry
bubo
buck
buff
bugs
buhl
buhr
bukh
bulb
bulk
bull
bumf
bump
bund
bung
bunk
bunn
bunt
buoy
burd
burg
burk
burl
burn
burp
burr
bury
bush
busk
buss
bust
busy
butt
buzz
byre
byte
cack
cade
cadi
caff
cage
cagy
caid
cain
cake
calf
calk
call
calm
calx
came
camp
canc
cane
cant
cany
capa
cape
caph
capo
caps
card
care
cark
carl
carn
carp
cart
casa
case
cash
cask
cast
cate
caul
caus
cave
cavy
cede
cedi
cell
celt
cent
cera
cere
cero
cert
cess
cete
chad
cham
chap
char
chat
chaw
chay
chef
chem
chew
chic
chin
chip
chit
chiv
chmn
chon
chop
chou
chow
choy
chub
chug
chum
cine
cion
circ
cist
city
clad
clam
clan
clap
clar
claw
clay
clef
cleg
clem
clew
clip
clod
clog
clop
clos
clot
clou
cloy
club
clue
coak
coal
coat
coax
cobb
coca
coch
cock
coco
coda
code
coed
coff
coft
coho
coif
coil
coin
coir
coit
coke
coky
cola
cold
cole
coll
colt
coly
coma
comb
come
comm
comp
conc
cond
cone
conf
cong
conk
conn
cons
cont
cony
coof
cook
cool
coom
coon
coop
coot
cope
copy
cord
core
corf
cork
corm
corn
corp
corr
cort
corv
cose
cosh
coss
cost
cosy
cote
coth
coud
coup
cove
cowl
coxa
coze
cozy
crab
crag
cram
cran
crap
craw
cray
cree
cres
crew
crib
crim
crit
crop
crow
crud
crum
crus
crux
csch
cube
cuda
cued
cuff
cuif
cull
culm
cult
cunt
curb
curd
cure
curf
curl
curn
curt
cusk
cusp
cuss
cute
cyan
cyke
cyma
cyme
cyst
czar
dace
dado
daff
daft
dago
dais
dale
dame
damn
damp
dang
dank
dard
dare
darg
dark
darn
dart
dash
data
date
dato
daub
daud
dauk
dawk
dawn
days
daze
dcor
dead
deaf
deal
dean
dear
debe
debt
decd
deck
decl
deed
deep
deer
defs
deft
defy
deil
dele
deli
dell
deme
demo
demy
dene
dens
dent
deny
dept
dere
dern
dero
derv
desc
desk
deva
dewy
dgag
dhak
dhal
dhow
diag
dial
diam
dice
dick
dict
dido
didy
dies
diet
diff
dike
dill
dime
ding
dink
dint
diol
dipl
dipt
dire
dirk
dirt
disc
dish
disk
dist
dita
diva
dive
divi
dixy
djin
dlvy
dmod
doab
dobl
dock
dodo
doek
doer
does
doge
dogy
doit
dojo
dole
doll
dols
dolt
dome
dona
done
dong
dook
doom
door
dopa
dope
dopy
dorm
dorp
dorr
dory
dose
doss
dost
doth
doty
douc
doup
dour
doux
dove
dowf
down
dowy
doxy
doze
dozy
drab
drag
dram
draw
dray
drch
dree
dreg
drew
drib
drip
drop
drub
drug
drum
drys
duad
dual
duce
duck
duct
dude
duel
duet
duff
duit
duka
duke
dulc
dull
duly
duma
dumb
dump
dune
dung
dunk
dunt
dupe
dura
dure
duro
dusk
dust
duty
dyad
dyer
dyke
dyne
each
earl
earn
ease
east
easy
eath
eave
ebon
ecad
eccl
echo
echt
ecol
econ
ecru
eddo
eddy
edge
edgy
edit
educ
eely
eery
efph
egal
egis
eild
elan
elem
elhi
elix
elmy
else
emeu
emir
emit
encl
ency
engr
enol
enow
entr
envy
epic
epit
epop
epos
eqpt
eric
erne
erst
esne
espy
esse
etna
etui
etym
even
ever
evil
ewer
exam
exch
excl
exec
exit
exon
expo
eyas
eyed
eyen
eyer
eyne
eyot
eyra
eyre
face
fact
fade
fado
fail
fain
fair
fake
fall
falx
fame
fana
fane
fang
fard
fare
farl
farm
faro
fart
fash
fast
fate
fath
fats
faun
fawn
feal
fear
feat
feck
feed
feel
feet
fell
felt
feme
fend
feod
fere
fern
ferv
fess
feta
fete
feud
fiar
fiat
fice
fico
fict
fief
fife
fike
fikh
file
fill
film
fils
filt
find
fine
fink
fino
fiqh
fire
firm
firn
fisc
fish
fist
five
fixt
fizz
flab
flag
flak
flam
flan
flap
flat
flav
flaw
flax
flea
fled
flee
flew
flex
fley
flip
flit
floc
floe
flog
flop
flor
flow
flub
flue
flux
foal
foam
foci
fogy
foil
foin
fold
folk
foll
fond
font
food
fool
foot
forb
ford
fore
fork
form
fort
foul
four
fowl
foxy
fozy
frag
frap
frat
fray
free
freq
fret
frig
fris
frit
friz
froe
frog
frow
frug
fuck
fuel
fugu
full
fume
fumy
fund
funk
furl
fury
fuse
fuss
fuze
fuzz
fyke
fyrd
gaby
gaff
gaga
gage
gain
gait
gala
gale
gall
gals
gamb
game
gamp
gamy
gang
gaol
gape
gapy
garb
gare
garg
gash
gasp
gata
gate
gaud
gaup
gaur
gave
gawk
gaze
gean
gear
geck
geek
geld
gelt
gems
gena
gene
gens
gent
genu
geod
geog
geol
geom
germ
gest
geum
ghat
ghee
gibe
gift
gild
gill
gilt
gimp
gink
gird
girl
girn
giro
girt
gist
give
glad
glee
gleg
glen
gley
glia
glib
glim
glob
glop
glow
glue
glum
glut
glyc
gnat
gnaw
goad
goaf
goal
goat
gobo
goby
goer
goes
gogo
gold
golf
golp
gone
gong
gonk
good
goof
goog
gook
goon
goop
gore
gory
gout
gowd
gowk
gown
gpad
gpcd
grab
grad
gram
grav
gray
gree
grew
grex
grey
grid
grig
grim
grin
grip
grit
grog
grok
grot
grow
grub
grum
guan
guar
guck
gude
guff
guib
gula
gulf
gull
gulp
gumi
gump
guna
gunk
guns
guru
gush
gust
gybe
gyre
gyro
gyve
haaf
haar
habu
hack
hade
hadj
haec
haem
haen
haet
haft
haik
hail
hair
haji
hajj
hake
hale
half
hall
halm
halo
halt
hame
hand
hang
hank
hant
hard
hare
harl
harm
harp
hart
hash
hask
hasp
hast
hate
hath
haul
have
hawk
haze
hazy
hdkf
head
heaf
heal
heap
hear
heat
heck
heed
heel
heer
heft
heir
held
hell
helm
help
heme
hemp
hent
herb
herd
here
herl
herm
hern
hero
herp
hest
heth
hewn
hick
hide
hied
high
hike
hill
hilt
hind
hint
hire
hiss
hive
hoar
hoax
hobo
hock
hoed
hoer
hogg
hold
hole
holm
holp
holt
holy
home
homo
homy
hone
hong
honk
hood
hoof
hook
hoop
hoot
hope
hora
horn
hort
hose
hosp
host
hour
hove
howe
howf
howl
hoya
hued
huff
huge
huia
hula
hulk
hull
huly
hump
hund
hung
hunk
hunt
hurl
hurt
hush
husk
hwan
hwyl
hyla
hymn
hype
hypo
hyte
iamb
ibex
ibid
ibis
iced
icky
icon
idea
idem
ides
idle
idly
idol
iffy
ijma
ikan
ikon
ilex
ilka
illy
ilth
imam
iman
imit
impf
impi
impv
inby
inch
incl
incr
inde
info
init
inky
inly
insp
inst
intr
invt
iota
iris
iron
isba
isle
isls
ital
itch
item
iter
iwis
ixia
izba
jaap
jack
jade
jaga
jail
jake
jamb
jane
jape
jarl
jasp
jass
jasy
jato
jaup
jawp
jazy
jazz
jean
jeep
jeer
jefe
jell
jerk
jess
jest
jger
jiao
jibe
jill
jilt
jimp
jink
jinn
jinx
jiva
jive
jock
joey
john
join
joke
jole
jolt
jook
josh
joss
jota
jouk
jour
jowl
juba
jube
judo
juju
jump
junk
jupe
jura
jury
just
jute
kadi
kago
kagu
kaif
kail
kain
kaka
kaki
kale
kali
kame
kami
kana
kane
kang
kans
kaon
kaph
karo
kart
kava
kayo
kcal
keap
keat
keck
keef
keek
keel
keen
keep
keet
keir
kelp
kelt
kemp
keno
kent
kepi
kept
kerb
kerf
kern
kero
keto
khan
khat
kibe
kick
kief
kier
kike
kill
kiln
kilo
kilt
kina
kind
kine
king
kink
kino
kirk
kirn
kish
kiss
kist
kite
kith
kiva
kiwi
kiyi
kmel
knag
knap
knar
knee
knew
knit
knob
knop
knot
know
knur
koan
koel
kohl
koko
kola
kolo
kona
kook
koph
kore
koso
koto
kris
krna
kudu
kueh
kula
kurn
kyak
kyat
kyle
kyte
lace
lack
lacy
lade
lady
laic
laid
laik
lain
lair
lake
lakh
laky
lama
lamb
lame
lamp
land
lane
lang
lank
lard
lark
larn
lash
lass
last
late
lath
lati
laud
lava
lave
lawn
laze
lazy
lead
leaf
leak
leal
lean
leap
lear
leat
lech
lect
leek
leer
leet
left
lehr
lend
leno
lens
lent
less
leud
levo
levy
lewd
lgth
liar
lice
lich
lick
lido
lied
lief
lien
lier
lieu
life
lift
like
lila
lilt
lily
limb
lime
limp
limy
line
ling
link
linn
lino
lint
liny
lion
lira
lisp
list
lith
litu
live
liza
ller
load
loaf
loam
loan
lobe
lobo
loca
loch
loci
lock
loco
lode
loft
loge
logo
logy
loin
loll
loma
lone
long
loof
look
loom
loon
loop
loot
lope
lord
lore
lorn
lory
lose
loss
lost
lota
lote
loth
lots
loud
loun
loup
lour
lout
love
lown
luau
lube
luce
luck
ludo
lues
luff
luge
lull
lulu
lump
lune
lung
lunt
luny
lure
lurk
lush
lust
lute
luxe
lwop
lych
lynx
lyre
lyse
maar
mace
mack
maco
made
mage
maid
mail
maim
main
mair
make
mako
male
mali
mall
malm
malt
mama
mana
mane
many
mara
marc
mare
marg
mark
marl
mart
mary
masc
mash
mask
mass
mass
mast
mate
math
matt
maud
maul
maun
maxi
maya
maze
mazy
mead
meal
mean
meat
mech
meck
meed
meek
meet
mela
meld
mell
melt
memo
mend
mene
meno
menu
merc
mere
merk
mesa
mesh
mess
meta
mete
mewl
mews
mica
mice
midi
mien
miff
mike
mild
mile
milk
mill
milo
milt
mime
mina
mind
mine
mini
mink
mint
minx
mire
mirk
miry
misc
mise
miso
miss
mist
mite
mitt
mixt
mmfd
moan
moat
mobs
mock
mode
mogo
moil
moir
moit
moke
mola
mold
mole
moll
molt
moly
mome
mona
mong
monk
mono
mons
mony
mood
moon
moor
moos
moot
mope
mopy
mora
more
morn
mort
moss
most
mote
moth
moue
move
mown
moxa
mrem
mtge
much
muck
muff
mule
mull
mump
munt
muon
murk
muse
mush
musk
muso
muss
must
mute
mutt
myna
myth
mzee
naif
nail
name
nana
nane
naos
nape
nard
nark
nary
natl
naut
nave
navy
neap
near
neat
neck
need
neep
nemo
nene
neon
nesh
ness
nest
nett
neuk
neut
news
newt
next
nice
nick
nide
nies
niff
nigh
nine
nipa
nisi
nock
node
nogg
noil
noir
noma
nome
none
nong
nook
noon
nope
nork
norm
nose
nosh
nosy
note
noun
nous
nova
nowt
nowy
nude
nuke
null
numb
nunc
nurl
nuts
oast
oath
obdt
obey
obit
oboe
odor
odyl
ofay
ogam
ogee
ogle
ogre
oily
okay
okra
okta
olid
olio
olla
omen
omer
omit
omni
once
oner
only
onus
onyx
oory
oose
ooze
oozy
opah
opal
open
opus
orad
oral
orca
orch
ordn
ordo
orfe
orgy
orig
orle
orlo
oryx
ossa
otic
otto
ouch
outr
ouzo
oval
oven
over
ovum
owed
oxen
oyer
oyez
paal
paca
pace
pack
pact
page
paho
paid
paik
pail
pain
pair
pale
pall
palm
palp
paly
pane
pang
pant
papa
para
pard
park
parr
pars
part
pase
pash
pass
past
pate
path
patt
paty
paua
pawl
pawn
payt
peag
peak
peal
pean
pear
peat
peba
pech
peck
peek
peel
peen
peep
peer
pegh
pein
peke
pele
pelf
pelt
peng
pent
peon
pepo
perh
peri
perk
perm
pert
perv
peso
pest
peto
phil
phiz
phon
phot
phut
phys
pial
pian
pias
pica
pice
pich
pick
pied
pier
piet
pigg
pika
pike
pile
pili
pill
pily
pimp
pine
ping
pink
pint
pinx
piny
pion
pipa
pipe
pipy
piqu
pirn
pish
piss
pita
pith
pity
pizz
plan
plat
play
plea
pleb
pled
plew
plie
plod
plop
plot
plow
ploy
plug
plum
plur
plus
pock
poco
poem
poet
pogy
poil
poke
poky
pole
poll
polo
poly
pome
pomp
pond
pone
pong
pons
pont
pony
pood
poof
pool
poon
poop
poor
pope
pops
pore
pork
port
pose
posh
post
posy
pott
pouf
pour
pout
prad
pram
prao
prat
prau
pray
pred
pref
prem
prep
pres
pret
prey
prig
prim
priv
proa
prob
proc
prod
prof
prog
prom
prop
pros
prov
prow
prox
psec
psia
psid
publ
puca
puce
puck
puff
puir
puja
puke
puku
puli
pull
pulp
pulu
puma
pump
puna
pung
punk
punt
puny
pupa
pure
purl
purr
push
puss
putt
pyic
pyin
pyre
qadi
qaid
qoph
quad
quag
quay
ques
quey
quid
quim
quin
quip
quit
quiz
quod
quor
quot
rabi
race
rack
racy
raff
raft
raga
rage
ragi
raia
raid
rail
rain
rake
raki
rale
rall
rami
ramp
rand
rang
rani
rank
rant
raob
rape
rapt
rare
rasa
rase
rash
rasp
rata
rate
rath
rave
razz
rcpt
rcvr
read
real
ream
reap
rear
reck
rect
redd
rede
redo
reed
reef
reek
reel
reen
refl
reft
rego
regr
reif
rein
reis
rely
rend
rent
repp
rept
resh
resp
rest
retd
rete
rgen
rhea
rheo
rhet
rial
rice
rich
rick
ride
riel
rife
riff
rift
rill
rime
rimu
rimy
rind
ring
rink
riot
ripe
rise
risk
rita
rite
ritz
rive
road
roak
roam
roan
roar
robe
rock
rode
roke
role
roll
romp
rone
rood
roof
rook
room
root
rope
ropy
rort
rose
ross
rosy
rota
rote
roti
rotl
roto
roue
roup
rout
roux
rove
rsum
rube
ruby
ruck
rudd
rude
rued
ruer
ruff
ruga
ruin
rule
rump
rune
rung
runt
ruse
rush
rusk
rust
ruth
ryal
ryke
ryot
sack
sadi
safe
saga
sage
sago
said
sail
sake
saki
sale
salt
same
samp
sand
sane
sang
sank
sant
sard
sari
sash
sass
sate
saut
save
sawn
says
scab
scad
scag
scan
scar
scat
scfh
scfm
scop
scot
scow
scry
scud
scum
scup
scut
seal
seam
sear
seat
sech
sect
seed
seek
seem
seen
seep
seer
sego
seif
self
sell
semi
sena
send
sent
sept
seqq
sera
sere
serf
seta
sett
sewn
sext
sexy
shad
shag
shah
sham
shaw
shay
shea
shed
shew
shim
shin
ship
shit
shiv
shod
shoe
shog
shoo
shop
shot
show
shpt
shtg
shul
shun
shut
shwa
sial
sice
sick
side
sigh
sign
sika
sike
sild
sile
silk
sill
silo
silt
sima
simp
sine
sing
sinh
sink
sire
site
sith
size
sizy
skat
skeg
sken
skep
sket
skew
skid
skim
skin
skip
skit
skua
slab
slag
slam
slap
slat
slaw
slay
sled
slew
sley
slid
slim
slip
slit
slob
sloe
slog
slop
slot
slow
slub
slue
slug
slum
slur
slut
smew
smit
smog
smug
smut
snag
snap
sned
snib
snip
snit
snob
snod
snog
snot
snow
snub
snug
snye
soak
soap
soar
sock
soda
sofa
soft
soil
soja
soke
sola
sold
sole
soli
solo
solv
soma
some
sone
song
sook
soom
soon
soot
sora
sorb
sore
sori
sort
souk
soul
soup
sour
sown
spae
spag
span
spar
spat
spec
sped
spew
spic
spif
spin
spit
spiv
spot
spry
spud
spue
spun
spur
srac
stab
stag
star
stat
staw
stay
stem
step
ster
stet
stew
stey
stge
stir
stlg
stoa
stob
stop
stot
stub
stud
stum
stun
subj
such
suck
sudd
sued
suer
suet
sugh
sugi
suit
sulk
sumi
sumo
sump
sung
sunk
sunn
supp
supr
sura
surd
sure
surf
surg
surv
susu
swab
swag
swam
swan
swap
swat
sway
swig
swim
swob
swop
swot
swum
syce
syke
syll
sync
synd
syne
syph
syst
tabi
tabu
tace
tack
taco
tact
tael
tahr
taig
tail
tain
taka
take
talc
tale
talk
tall
tame
tana
tang
tanh
tank
tapa
tape
taps
tare
tarn
taro
tarp
tart
task
tass
taut
taws
taxi
tchr
teak
teal
team
tear
teat
tech
teed
teel
teen
teff
teil
tela
tele
tell
temp
tend
tent
tepe
term
tern
terr
test
teth
text
thae
thak
thar
that
thaw
then
thew
thin
thio
this
thou
thru
thud
thug
thus
tick
tidy
tied
tier
tiff
tike
tiki
tile
till
tilt
time
tine
ting
tint
tiny
tipi
tire
tirl
tiro
titi
toad
tobe
toby
tody
toea
toed
toey
toff
toft
toga
toil
tola
told
tole
toll
tolu
tomb
tome
tone
tong
tonk
tonn
tony
took
tool
toom
toon
toot
tope
toph
topi
tops
torc
tore
tori
torn
toro
torr
tort
tosh
toss
tost
tote
tour
tout
town
towy
trad
tram
trap
trav
tray
tree
tref
trek
tres
tret
trey
trid
trig
trig
trim
trio
trip
trit
trod
trog
trop
trot
trow
troy
true
trug
tsar
tuba
tube
tuck
tufa
tuff
tuft
tule
tump
tuna
tune
turd
turf
turn
tush
tusk
tutu
twat
twee
twig
twin
twit
tyke
type
typo
typw
tyre
tyro
tyum
tzar
udal
ugli
ugly
ulan
ulna
ulto
umpy
unau
unct
undo
ungt
unit
univ
upas
urdy
urea
urge
uric
urus
used
user
uvea
vaad
vail
vain
vair
vale
vamp
vane
vang
vara
vary
vase
vast
veal
veep
veer
veil
vein
vela
veld
vena
vend
vent
verb
vers
vert
very
vesp
vest
veto
vial
vice
vide
vied
vier
view
vile
vina
vine
vino
viny
viol
virl
visa
vise
vita
vite
vivo
vlei
void
vole
vols
volt
vote
vulg
vvll
wack
wade
wadi
waff
waft
wage
waif
wail
wain
wait
waka
wake
wale
walk
wall
wame
wand
wane
wank
want
warb
ward
ware
wark
warm
warn
warp
wart
wary
wase
wash
wasp
wast
watt
wauk
waur
wave
wavy
wawa
wawl
waxy
ways
weak
weal
wean
wear
weed
week
ween
weep
weer
weft
weir
weka
weld
well
welt
wend
went
wept
were
wert
west
wham
whap
what
when
whet
whey
whim
whin
whip
whir
whit
whiz
whop
whse
wick
wide
wife
wild
wile
will
wilt
wily
wind
wine
wing
wink
wino
winy
wipe
wire
wiry
wise
wish
wisp
wist
wite
wive
wkly
woad
woke
wold
wolf
womb
wont
wood
woof
wool
word
wore
work
worm
worn
wort
wove
wrap
wren
writ
wynd
wynn
wyte
xylo
xyst
yack
yank
yapp
yard
yare
yarn
yate
yaud
yaup
yawl
yawn
yawp
yeah
yean
year
yegg
yeld
yelk
yell
yelp
yeti
yett
yeuk
yike
ylem
yoga
yogh
yogi
yoke
yolk
yoni
yore
yous
yowl
yuan
yule
yurt
ywis
zack
zany
zarf
zeal
zebu
zein
zero
zest
zeta
ziff
zila
zinc
zing
zoea
zone
zool
zoom
zoon
```

Comment: I've got your non-ASCII ones covered. :)

Comment: Thanks, I knew how to do it but I was just being lazy :p

Comment: YOU'RE AMAZING THANK YOU. This is exactly what I needed. Sorry, I really just had no clue how to do it myself or a site that could do it for me. Thanks so much! Also I'm really surprised at how few words there are that match this criteria, which is part of why I was interested. There's like thousands and thousands or whatever normally, and now it's...kind of a relatively small amount.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Unix system, or at least something where you can install Perl CPAN modules, then after you install [the `Unicode::Tussle` distro](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::Tussle), you can run simple command-line checks like:

```
% unilook --pos noun '^\w{4}\b' | wc -l
4418

% unilook --pos verb '^\w{4}\b' | wc -l
1858

% unilook --pos adjective '^\w{4}\b' | wc -l
737

% unilook --pos adverb '^\w{4}\b' | wc -l
142

% unilook --pos pronoun '^\w{4}\b' | wc -l
22
```

That won't normally count obsolete words, but you can add options to include those as well.

And it will notice such non-ASCII hits as:

```
abbé [n.]
ælf [n.]
aîné [adj.]
bébé [n.]
bœuf [n.]
café [n.]
caña [n.]
cèpe [n.]
cœur [n.]
Chün [n.]
ciré [adj.]
curé [n.]
Doña [n.]
doré [adj.]
élan [n.]
épée [n.]
fanā [n.]
fête [n.]
fête [v.]
föhn [n.]
fumé [adj.]
gêne [n.2]
gêné [adj.]
goût [n.]
grès [n.]
Günz [n.]
idée [n.]
inée [n.]
jeté [n.]
Jōdo [n.]
kaïd [n.]
káns [n.]
lamé [n.3]
maté [n.3]
mère [n.]
Moët [n.]
naïd [n.]
naïf [adj.]
naïs [n.]
Néel [n.]
névé [n.]
noué [adj.]
ombú [n.]
ondé [n.]
orné [adj.3]
pamé [adj.]
Pará [n.2]
pâte [n.4]
pâté [n.3]
pavé [n.2]
père [n.]
piña [n.]
pisé [n.]
plié [n.]
posé [adj.]
râle [n.]
ramé [adj.]
raté [adj.]
Rōjū [n.]
rosé [n.2]
rôti [n.1]
roué [n.]
rusé [adj.]
saké [n.2]
sève [n.]
stød [n.]
tête [n.]
topī [n.1]
très [adv.]
visé [n.3]
visé [v.2]
vœu [n.]
Würm [n.]
yagé [n.]
yüeh [n.4]
Yüeh [n.1]
Yüeh [n.2]
Yüeh [n.3]
Zuñi [n.]
```

Just to name a few.

Answer (score -1):

There is a downloadable list of English words that are valid in the word game "Scrabble". This is quite a comprehensive list and can be found at https://www.wordgamedictionary.com/sowpods/download/sowpods.txt.

I suggest you use this in combination with Microsoft Excel (or a similar spreadsheet) and an appropriate formula.

Comment: I think that list does not have parts of speech.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference; it's easier to make up a stop list of the closed class words and just delete them from the list. There are **FAR** fewer of those than there are of open class words. It's not necessary to determine the POS as long as it's a word from an open class.